# How to Pass Uri of blob storage as Input BAPI parameter

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have Input BAPI Parameters in xml file stored in blob container and can one give me idea on how to pass the BLOB SAS URI of stored file as  Parameter to BAPI Call method in SAP for Azure Logic App

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds that you can try is to use the `Create SAS URI by path (V2)` connector and then use `Shared access Signature` for your BAPI call method.

[image]